# put restrictions on the web page

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, spring, web

how can I put my web page secure so it does not get redirected when writing a route in the browser

example

http: // localhost: 8080 / home / showList

then I change to another form and do this

I delete showList and I write addProduct
http: // localhost: 8080 / home / addProduct

and it enters without problems, my doubt is there will be some recommendation so that it does not allow to be redirected when writing the URL directly as I put in the example, that has restrictions and does not accede as easily

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain what restrictions you require to be met to be able to go to addProduct?  For example, needing to be authenticated before allowing anyone to go to addProduct?  Or having the referrer come from a certain page?

Comment: what I want to do is not to access the page when I manually write the route as I show in the example
This is the main page
http: // localhost: 8080 / home /

and then I add the following "addProduct" to the end of the route

http: // localhost: 8080 / home / addProduct

and redirects me to the addproduct form

I do not want that to be allowed, because in the future any user can easily access another form by typing the name of the forms and accessing it directly from the url

Comment: Use [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to modify the URL without physically navigating to it.